# Rows not combining properly because of CASE?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to find the SUM of TotalSales for multiple product groups, but some groups have more than one product group in them. I thought a CASE would work, but my output is not combining the TotalSales properly.

What concept am I missing here? And what would I need to do to fix it?

QUERY:

```
SELECT
    SA3.SalesRepID,
    CASE SA3.ProductGroup1ID
        WHEN  3 THEN  3
        WHEN  8 THEN  8
        WHEN 14 THEN 14
        WHEN 20 THEN 14
        WHEN  5 THEN 14
        WHEN  9 THEN  9
        WHEN 10 THEN  9
        WHEN 11 THEN  9
        WHEN 16 THEN 16
        WHEN 17 THEN 17
        WHEN 19 THEN 19
        ELSE 1 END AS [ProductGroupID],
    SA3.BranchID,
    MONTH(SA3.DocumentDate) [Month],
    YEAR(SA3.DocumentDate) [Year],
    SUM(TotalSales)

FROM SalesAnalysis3 SA3
LEFT JOIN SalesRep SR ON SR.SalesRepID = SA3.SalesRepID

WHERE SR.UserID = 17

GROUP BY SA3.SalesRepID,[ProductGroup1ID],
   SA3.BranchID, MONTH(SA3.DocumentDate), YEAR(SA3.DocumentDate)

ORDER BY
CASE WHEN MONTH(SA3.DocumentDate) < 3 THEN MONTH(SA3.DocumentDate) +12
ELSE MONTH(SA3.DocumentDate) END, YEAR(SA3.DocumentDate), SA3.BranchID, [ProductGroupID]
```

SAMPLE OUTPUT:

```
    SalesRepID  ProductGroupID  BranchID    Month   Year    TotalSales
    17          1               3           3       2014    900.60
    17          1               3           3       2014    1307.24
    17          1               3           3       2014    1735.15
    17          1               3           3       2014    402.65
    17          3               3           3       2014    760.00
    17          8               3           3       2014    28783.14
```

Comment: Your `GROUP BY` doesn't match the non-aggregate items in your `SELECT` list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to edit your group by to use your case statement.  Right now you're editing the product ID in the select, but still grouping on the original product ID.

Replace:

```
GROUP BY SA3.SalesRepID,[ProductGroup1ID],
  SA3.BranchID, MONTH(SA3.DocumentDate), YEAR(SA3.DocumentDate)
```

with:

```
GROUP BY SA3.SalesRepID
,   SA3.BranchID, MONTH(SA3.DocumentDate), YEAR(SA3.DocumentDate),
CASE SA3.ProductGroup1ID
    WHEN  3 THEN  3
    WHEN  8 THEN  8
    WHEN 14 THEN 14
    WHEN 20 THEN 14
    WHEN  5 THEN 14
    WHEN  9 THEN  9
    WHEN 10 THEN  9
    WHEN 11 THEN  9
    WHEN 16 THEN 16
    WHEN 17 THEN 17
    WHEN 19 THEN 19
    ELSE 1 END
```

Comment: @Kaiguy - I am glad this helped, and thank you for writing such a clear first question.  Please accept the answer if you do not need more help on this question.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with araphael's answer, but I think you should simplify the `case` statement:

```
(CASE WHEN SA3.ProductGroup1ID in (14, 20, 5) THEN 14
      WHEN SA3.ProductGroup1ID in (9, 10, 11) THEN 9
      WHEN SA3.ProductGroup1ID in (3, 8, 16, 17, 19) THEN SA3.ProductGroup1ID
      ELSE 1
 END) AS [ProductGroupID]
```